# Nginx configuration server_name without vhost

Tags: nginx

I am trying to make nginx work but I do not know how set server_name in nginx configuration.

Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name     ~localhost\/<domain>\/www\/(.)*$;
    set             $try_dir $domain;

    root /media/andrew/data/www/hosts/$try_dir/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|gitignore) { # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's $
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.(neon|ini|log|yml)$ { # deny access to configuration files
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I need access to my projects by url: **http://localhost/project_name/www**

Now I get 404 response. I think that problem is in regular expression in server_name. Can somebody help me with configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The server name is the string that is expected to be in the host portion of the URI.

if you want to only access your project from localhost then the sever_name will be localhost

The NGINX documentation is pretty good at explaining. it can be found here.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: When I have in server_name only localhost then a get response 404. I neeed write to server_name regular expression for detect project name.